# require() of ES Module myRoute\node_modules\inquirer\lib\prompts\base.js not supported

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, inquirer

I have an application built with Angular 17, Ionic 7 and I wish to use firebase firestore services, to do that I need to use `@angular/fire` library, but when I try to install and use version 17 of Fire with

```
ng add @angular/fire
```

I get the following CommonJS modules:

```
require() of ES Module miRuta\node_modules\inquirer\lib\prompts\base.js from 
  miRuta\node_modules\inquirer-autocomplete-prompt\index.js not supported. 
Instead change the require of base.js in 
  miRuta\node_modules\inquirer-autocomplete-prompt\index.js to a dynamic import()
which is available in all CommonJS modules.
```

I tried changing a lot of things in `tsconfig.json`, uninstalling `inquirer`, and with Angular 16 too, but I had no luck.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem trying to install angular/fire. Just update inquier plugin

```
npm install inquirer-autocomplete-prompt@^3.0.1
```

Then, try to install angular/fire again

Comment: Oh boy, I was struggling with this an entire day. Thank you very much, you are the best!!!